# C# sending, receive and redirection of string messages between objects

Tags: c#

I have main class 'Template' which have references to some processors 'IProcessor'

```
 interface IProcessor
{
    void Execute();
}

class Template
{
    IProcessor proc1;
    IProcessor proc2;
    IProcessor proc3;

    public Template(IProcessor p1, IProcessor p2, IProcessor p3)
    {
        proc1 = p1;
        proc2 = p2;
        proc3 = p3;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        proc1.Execute();
        proc2.Execute();
        proc3.Execute();
    }
}
```

Every processor need to have ability to send string messages to 'Template' class. 'Template' class need to have ability to redirect messages to other objects (maybe Logger or to UI).

The problem in that the Run method() of 'Template' can be started in a separate Thread, and messages in IProcessor can be generated in Parallel.Foreach loop. My decision is consolidated to Producer/Consumer pattern realization where there is BlockingCollection using, but I feel that this is too expensive for my problem, besides there are difficulties in the redirection of arriving messages to other objects. Is there a standard solution to this problem? (Events, delegates or something else?)

Comment: You already mentioned some possible solutions: pass a delegate to a method that retrieves the string to the processor; raise an event in the processor when a new message is ready; let `Template` implement an interface and pass this to the processor. The most appropriate solution depends on your architecture.

Comment: Why do you think using BlockingCollection would be too heavy, this seems the natural solution? And moreover what are the "difficulties" you're talking about? You'll need some synchronization somewhere and a blocking collection is a good place to "hide" it. :)

Comment: collecting strings is a common area and thus a critical section.

Comment: I'm failing to understand the complexity of the problem. If your `Template` needs a message from `IProcessor` then why not change `void Execute` to `string Execute` or whatever object needs to be passed back.

Comment: Messages generates inside Execute() method in Parallel.Foreach loop, so i don't need string Execute(). Generated messages are sends to Template, and then redirect to other objects.